# Does RequireJS provide a dependency api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I would like to pass a requireJS `config.json` and a source file like my `main.js` and receive a list of all its dependencies.

This is probably part of the `r.js` optimization application however I couldn't find any documentation about its inner structure.

Does RequireJS provide such an api to generate a dependency list?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API that I know of. However, if you run `r.js` (the optimizer) with a build configuration like this:

```
({
    baseUrl: ...,
    dir: ...,
    mainConfigFile: ".../config.js",
    findNestedDependencies: true,
    name: "main",
    optimize: "none"
})
```

then you'll get a `build.txt` file in the directory where you specify to store the optimized build (the value of `dir`). The general format of this file is:

```
<output-file1>
----------------
<module A>
<module B>

<output-file2>
----------------
<module C>
<module D>
```

This tells you that the output file `output-file1` contains modules `A` and `B`, `output-file2` contains modules `C` and `D`.

With the configuration I suggested above, you should have only one output file listed in the `build.txt` file for your main module, and the list of modules listed under it are all the modules it depends on.

In the configuration above I've set `optimize: "none"` because it would save time if the only thing you care about is dependencies. In a real build you'd want to let `r.js` use uglifyjs to minify your code. Also, `findNestedDependencies: true` is there to tell `r.js` to find dynamic calls to `require` in the middle of your code. And thins brings up a major warning. If you have this:

```
if (blah)
    require(["foo"], function (foo) {...});
```

then `findNestedDependencies: true` will be able to detect that there is a dependency on the module `foo`. However, there is no way for `r.js` to handle this:

```
var module_name = obj[key];
require([module_name], function (module) {...});
```

To know what module this code is loading, `r.js` would have to execute the code (and even then there's a limit to what code execution can discover).